# PowerShell remote call. Access is denied from webserver

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, powershell-3.0

i write a code for remote access for exchange powershell from asp.net application to enable remote mail using vb.net and exchange 2016
the command run successfully from my visual studio debug
but when i put in iis web server it's giving me

> Connecting to remote server "" failed with the following error
>   message : Access is denied

this is is the code

```
Function enableRemoteEmail(ByVal samaccount As String, ByVal email As String) As String
    Dim ServerUri As String = "http://{mailserver}/powershell" 
    Dim SchemaUri As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange"
    Dim userName As String = AccountOperatorLogon 
    Dim password As New System.Security.SecureString
    For Each x As Char In AccountOperatorPassword
        password.AppendChar(x)
    Next

    Dim PSCredential As New PSCredential(userName, password)
    Dim ConnectionInfo As WSManConnectionInfo = New WSManConnectionInfo(New Uri(ServerUri), SchemaUri, PSCredential)
    ConnectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic
    Dim RemoteRunspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ConnectionInfo)
    Dim RemotePowerShell As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create
    RemotePowerShell.AddCommand("Enable-RemoteMailbox")
    RemotePowerShell.AddParameter("Identity", samaccount)
    RemotePowerShell.AddParameter("RemoteRoutingAddress",email )
    RemotePowerShell.AddParameter("Credential", PSCredential)

    ' Open the remote runspace on the server.
    RemoteRunspace.Open()
    ' Associate the runspace with the Exchange Management Shell.
    RemotePowerShell.Runspace = RemoteRunspace
    Dim TheResult As Collection(Of PSObject)
    Dim TheResultString As String = ""
    TheResult = RemotePowerShell.Invoke
    For Each RSLT As PSObject In TheResult
        TheResultString += RSLT.ToString() + "<br/>"
    Next
    RemoteRunspace.Close()
    ' Invoke the Exchange Management Shell to run the command.
    Return TheResultString
End Function
```

Comment: Probably a permissions issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2905767/-access-is-denied-error-when-you-connect-to-exchange-online-by-using-remote-windows-powershell

Comment: i run the code under user PSCredential it's working in the debug mode but in the web server not working

Comment: Sometimes web servers are locked down in DMZs and may not be connected to the domain, so referencing the AccountOperatorLogon 
 and AccountOperatorPassword could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution for anyone have the same problem

1. create user as a member of (Recipient Management group)
2. IIS change (for exchange server) navigate to IIS Manager | Default Website | PowerShell Change the physical path from: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\PowerShell` to: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\PowerShell`

3.After the change: IISRESET

and it will work fine

Comment: Man you saved me, i'm struggling this issue for almost 3 days, did not found a solution, i said ok, it's time to ask a question in stackoverflow, then i saw this in suggested answers list, and wow- this is working, many thanks, i edited your question with full error message, so it will be easier for others to find